# How to set up a unit test (qUnit) in SAP UI5?

Tags: unit-testing, qunit, sapui5

I'm trying to add unit tests (using qUnit) for my simple SAP UI5 Application. From my understanding the main files you need include:

- initialTest.html (where the testing is bootstrapped)
- qunit.js (framework library)
- qunit.css (framework stylesheet)
- test.js (where the unit tests will be written)
- target code (the source file that contains the code to be tested)

The problem I'm facing is loading in the desired target code for testing.

I have the following basic file structure

[image]

Here is where I need help, how can properly reference the code file in my tests.js? (ie: I want to test the code situated in Main.controller.js)

**tests.js**

```
sap.ui.require(["Controller/Main.controller.js"],

function(MyController){
   //Quint code
   test("hello test", function(assert) {
    assert.ok(1 == "1", "Passed!");
  });
  });
```

**initialTest.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>QUnit Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.css">
          <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js">
          </script>    
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.15.0.js"></script>
          <script src="tests.js"></script>
          <script src="/Controller/Main.controller.js"></script>          
          <script>
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="qunit"></div>
      <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I hope this link helps you [OPENUI5 Unit Test](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.8/docs/guide/e1ce1de315994a02bf162f4b3b5a9f09.html)

Answer (score 0):

The question does not convey the right problem as I see you are facing issue while trying to refer Controller file of your application and not in the qUnit tests.

Here's how you should refer files

```js
sap.ui.require(
 [
  "sap/ui/demo/wt/controller/Master",         <--- path to your Controller file
 ],
 function (MasterController) {

    //refer methods of controller file
    //MasterController.methodName
}
```

You can read more about sap.ui.require here: [documentation](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/jquery.sap.global.js#L2488)

Nevertheless, if you are looking at more details on qUnits, you can refer the following documents:

- [how to setup unit tests](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/e1/ce1de315994a02bf162f4b3b5a9f09/content.htm?no_cache=true)
- [blog on setting unit test](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/30/testing-ui5-apps-part-1-setup-and-unit-testing/)
- [Qunit Fundamentals](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_scm700_ehp03/helpdata/en/70/8002929ea548fd9433954a9275eb5f/frameset.htm)

Let me know if this helps!